# Update SQL does not work in vba but works in Query Design?

Tags: ms-access

I have a function that simply updates records in a table: When this function is called, the SQL runs without error but the table doesn't actually update.

I re-ran the function this time printing out the SQL to the Immediate window, and when I copy/paste that SQL into the Query Design it runs correctly. This function is called up to 20,000 times in a run, and all of the SQL statements printed out into the Immediate window seem to work when run in Query Design.

```
mysql = "UPDATE IRG_MasterScr "
mysql = mysql & "SET IRG_MasterScr.ScrName = " & MyScrLuID & ", "
mysql = mysql & "IRG_MasterScr.Interp_Short = " & Interp_Short & ", "
mysql = mysql & "IRG_MasterScr.Stdt_Interp = " & Stdt_Interp & ", "
mysql = mysql & "IRG_MasterScr.Adv_Interp = " & Adv_Interp & ", "
mysql = mysql & "IRG_MasterScr.IRG_Score = " & LU02 & " "
mysql = mysql & "WHERE (((IRG_MasterScr.Master_Scr_ID)=" & MasterID & "));"
Debug.Print "SQL: " & vbNewLine & mysql & vbNewLine

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL mysql
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

I'm expecting to see records updated in IRG_MasterScr table, but no records are updated. Again, there are no errors thrown and the SQL statements (mysql) runs fine when cut/pasted into Query Design.

Comment: Comment out the SetWarnings and see what message pops up. Are these fields all number type? If any are text type, then need apostrophe delmiters: `='" & Interp_Short & "', "`. Date/time requires # delimiter.

Comment: Thanks. All fields are numeric, no dates or strings. Ran the function with the setwarnings disabled and still got the same problem, no errors thrown.

Comment: RunSQL should trigger warning popups, not necessarily errors. I prefer CurrentDb.Execute and then don't have to use SetWarnings code. I don't see anything wrong with the SQL construction.

Comment: I agree, and ultimately since I couldn't fix this issue, I went to the DAO query approach. I still don't know why it wouldn't work, but I compacted/repaired the DB and wrote the code for DAO query instead and it seems to work fine now. (Could be that the problem was a corrupted database).